# Why can't I add a variable to GIMP plugin?

Tags: python, gimp, python-fu, gimpfu

Ok, I am trying to develop a small plugin for gimp that makes a bitmap font. For some reason now that I added the following code it won't work.

```
current_cell_x = 0
current_cell_y = 0

x_pos = current_cell_x * cwidth
y_pos = current_cell_y * cheight

x_pos += cwidth / 2.0
y_pos += cheight / 2.0

x_pos -= text_layer.width / 2.0
y_pos -= text_layer.height / 2.0
```

Even just the first line with 'current_cell_x = 0' is enough to make the entire plugin not work.

Here is all the code in a working format:

```
from gimpfu import *

def create_font(cwidth, cheight, xcells, ycells, font, size, color) :

    char_begin = 32
    char_end = 127
    num_chars = char_end - char_begin

    #current_cell_x = 0
    #current_cell_y = 0

    # Figure out total width & height
    twidth = int(cwidth * xcells)
    theight = int(cheight * ycells)

    # Create Image
    img = gimp.Image(twidth, theight, RGB)
    img.disable_undo()

    # Save the current foreground color:
    pdb.gimp_context_push()

    # Set the text color & background color
    gimp.set_foreground(color)
    gimp.set_background(0, 0, 0)

    # Create All Layers & Position Accordingly
    for i in range(char_begin, char_end):
        string = '%c' % i
        offset = i - char_begin
        text_layer = pdb.gimp_text_fontname(img, None, 0, 0, string, -1, True, size, PIXELS, font)

        #x_pos = current_cell_x * cwidth
        #y_pos = current_cell_y * cheight

        #x_pos += cwidth / 2.0
        #y_pos += cheight / 2.0

        #x_pos -= text_layer.width / 2.0
        #y_pos -= text_layer.height / 2.0

    #pdb.gimp_image_flatten(img)

    img.enable_undo()

    # Create a new image window
    gimp.Display(img)
    # Show the new image window
    gimp.displays_flush()

    # Restore the old foreground color:
    pdb.gimp_context_pop()

register(
    "python_fu_bitmap_font",
    "Bitmap Font",
    "Create a new bitmap font",
    "*****",
    "*****",
    "2013",
    "Bitmap Font (Py)...",
    "",      # Create a new image, don't work on an existing one
    [
        (PF_SPINNER, "cwidth", "Cell Width", 24, (1, 3000, 1)),
        (PF_SPINNER, "cheight", "Cell Height", 51, (1, 3000, 1)),
        (PF_SPINNER, "xcells", "Cells on X axis", 10, (1, 3000, 1)),
        (PF_SPINNER, "ycells", "Cells on Y axis", 10, (1, 3000, 1)),
        (PF_FONT, "font", "Font face", "Consolas"),
        (PF_SPINNER, "size", "Font size", 50, (1, 3000, 1)),
        (PF_COLOR, "color", "Text color", (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    ],
    [],
    create_font, menu="<Image>/File/Create")

main()
```

However, when I un-comment lines 9 - 10 & lines 33 - 40 I get the following errors.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I wanted my final code to look something like this:

```
def create_font(cwidth, cheight, xcells, ycells, font, size, color) :

    char_begin = 32
    char_end = 127
    num_chars = char_end - char_begin

    current_cell_x = 0
    current_cell_y = 0

    # Figure out total width & height
    twidth = int(cwidth * xcells)
    theight = int(cheight * ycells)

    # Create Image
    img = gimp.Image(twidth, theight, RGB)
    img.disable_undo()

    # Save the current foreground color:
    pdb.gimp_context_push()

    # Set the text color & background color
    gimp.set_foreground(color)
    gimp.set_background(0, 0, 0)

    # Create All Layers & Position Accordingly
    for i in range(char_begin, char_end):
        string = '%c' % i

        text_layer = pdb.gimp_text_fontname(img, None, 0, 0, string, -1, True, size, PIXELS, font)
        pdb.plug_in_autocrop_layer(0, img, text_layer)

        x_pos = float(current_cell_x * cwidth)
        y_pos = float(current_cell_y * cheight)

        x_pos += float(cwidth) / 2.0
        y_pos += float(cheight) / 2.0

        x_pos -= float(text_layer.width) / 2.0
        y_pos -= float(text_layer.height) / 2.0

        text_layer.translate(x_pos, y_pos)

        #Set current cell
        current_cell_x += 1
        if current_cell_x > xcells:
            current_cell_x = 0
            current_cell_y += 1
        if current_cell_y > ycells:
            break

        gimp.progress_update(float(offset) / float(num_chars))

    #pdb.gimp_image_flatten(img) # Don't do this

    img.enable_undo()

    # Create a new image window
    gimp.Display(img)
    # Show the new image window
    gimp.displays_flush()

    # Restore the old foreground color:
    pdb.gimp_context_pop()
```

If you see any suggestions as far as that goes, I wouldn't mind.

Note: Got my code from - https://github.com/sole/snippets/blob/master/gimp/generate_bitmap_font/sole_generate_bitmap_font.py and http://gimpbook.com/scripting/

---

Ran 'python -tt plugin.py' and got the following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you use consistent indentation? Spaces everywhere? Or might there be some leading tabs?

Comment: @Matthias What is the best way to check for that? (Not exactly the most visible thing) - I am pretty sure indentation, spaces, tabs are all the way they should be. - I use tabs for everything. No spaces for indentation despite just reading that I should use the other.

Comment: Run `python -tt yourscript.py`.

Comment: @Matthias Ran it and got TabError. It is last image on question, just added. I tried to re-write the code by hand, but still nothing. What should I do?

Comment: @Matthias Ok, so finally was able to run reindent.py from the Python33/Tools/Scripts and did not work. Check it again. Still not working with gimp, but now I am getting an IndentationError. Will add the image of it in a minute. - Also, I am using Notepad++... could that be an issue?

Comment: @Matthias Ok, you were pretty much right. If you submit an answer saying that I had inconsistent indentation & to use your run code & that I needed to go to Settings>Preferences>Language Menu/Tab Settings>Tab Settings and then check Replace by space... I will accept your answer. You led me to the answer and couldn't have done it without you. Thanks again! Btw the problem was my editor. It was not replacing the tabs correctly if at all and now does it fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had inconsistent indentation I needed to go to Settings>Preferences>Language Menu/Tab Settings>Tab Settings and then check Replace by space.

Then I needed to run

```
python -tt yourscript.py
```

Which allowed me to get rid of all the indention errors that were caused by my edior.

I also used  reindent.py from the Python33/Tools/Scripts folder, but it did not work for me. It may have helped in someway I did not see.

Matthias was halfway right, but he did not submit an answer. I am doing that in his place.

Answer (score 2):

The error on the CMD windows says it: you are mixing tabs and spaces in your source code - 
make sure the lines you add to the code are prefixed with spaces only, and not tab (\x09) characters.

You should configure the editor program you are using to edit the Python code not to use tab characters at all.

(it could possibly be the other way around, you are editing a file idented with tabs, and your editor is properly configured to use spaces - you should replace all tabs in that case)

Check the Python style guide document:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/